# Prefixing function names

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that many people around the site, when writing PHP functions as part of an answer, prefix it with something like `wpse_101042`. I assume that this is to prevent duplicate function name errors.

Is this a widely accepted standard on WP SE, or simply a commonly used practice?

In an answer, is the number the *question* ID or the actual *post* (answer) ID?

Comment: I tend to use `wpa_XXXX`...where `wpa` stands for WordPress Answers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is usually just a personal preference.  As Bainternet states, it is *always* a good practice to prefix function names in WordPress.  And while it's not required on this site, consider the sheer number of people who just copy and paste code into their projects.

Using a `wpse_XXX` prefix does a couple of things:

1. It prevents sites that contain copy-pasted code from breaking with duplicate function names
2. It helps identify *which* copy-pasted code came from this site.

Number 2 is merely a fun, unintended result of the practice.  But the number of client sites I've seen with `wpse_XXX` littered around their themes and plugins is entertaining and, to me at least, proves just how much the code snippets we post are used.

So to answer your specific questions:

> Is this a widely accepted standard on WP SE, or simply a commonly used practice?

Just a commonly used practice based on a widely accepted best practice.

> In an answer, is the number the question ID or the actual post (answer) ID?

Usually the question ID since, typically, you don't know your answer's ID until after you've posted it.

Answer (score 8):

Its Always a good practice to `prefix` you function names when it comes to WordPress.

When i use it i simple put the id of the question but lately I started to `postfix` the function names so the function has the meaning full name first and the a unique ID (`wpse_XXXX`) which makes more sense to me and its easier to understand when I go back and read over the code.

But  to answer your question (question/answer id) or even use `wpse_XXXX` is not a must but it is becoming an accepted standard by those who want to follow it.

Bottom line: *Do what ever feels right for you*.

Comment: Postfixing makes a lot of sense, much easier to read, I'll buy it!